# alsa softvol does not show up in amixer

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I have a orangepi pc and need to setup an alsa softvol pcm to control the i2s dac volume.

Therefore I have create the following /etc/asound.conf

```
pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave.pcm "softvol"
}
pcm.softvol {
  type  softvol
  slave {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
  }
  control {
    name  "SoftVol"
    card  1
  }
}
```

and here are the detected devices

```
root@orangepipcplus:~# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: audiocodec [audiocodec], device 0: SUNXI-CODEC sndcodec-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: snddaudio [snddaudio], device 0: SUNXI-TDM0 snddaudio-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: sndhdmi [sndhdmi], device 0: SUNXI-HDMIAUDIO sndhdmi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

For some reason controlling the volume with `alsamixer` does nothing. And if I change the control block in the asound.conf from `SoftVol` to e.g. `Master` no control with the name `Master` appears in alsamixer after a reboot.

So my nasty suspicion is that my /etc/asound.conf is not read by alsa!

The OS I am using is Armbian -> Debian.

I have another pi (nanopi) also running Armbian -> Debian using the same /etc/asound.conf and there everything is working.

Comment: not about alsa, but about "doesn't read": run `inotifywait -m /etc/asound.conf` (from inotify-tools) with appropriate privileges (best as root) to see real-time if the file is actually read or not.

Comment: ok the file is getting read. following [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=157290) I managed to get the old `SoftVol` device to disappear but the newly created `Master` SoftVol does not appear

Comment: I vaguely remember that sunxi does some funny non-standard things related to sound, so that may (or may not) cause this problem. At least it's an aspect to look at.

Comment: It is working on a NanoPi Neo. This device is using sunxi H3 too. I copied all alsa stuff from there but no softvol appears.

Answer (score 2):

The mixer will not show up until it is used for the first time. Per [alsa.opensrc.org](https://alsa.opensrc.org/How_to_use_softvol_to_control_the_master_volume):

> **Note:** The new volume control won't appear immediately! Only after the first
>   usage of the newly defined device (e.g. with the command above), should
>   `amixer controls | grep <control name>` display your new control. Mixers that
>   were already started before the first usage (like KMix) have to be restarted to
>   adopt the changes. If you still don't see the new control, try restarting ALSA or
>   your PC.

Since your config sets the default to the softvol device, running `speaker-test` or using `aplay` to play a .wav file should be sufficient to make the volume control appear.